# PHP mail() - showing more addresses in "To" field than are actually sent to

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I'm working on a list server of sorts, and I'm using PHP's mail() function. I'm trying to figure out a way to have the recipient see multiple addresses in the To: field, without PHP actually sending to those addresses. For example:

- the email list "webmasters@company.com" should forward to "john@company.com" and "mary@company.com"
- an email is sent from an individual to "jack@agency.org" and "webmasters@company.com"
- the list server receives the email to "webmasters@company.com", and wants to forward it appropriately
- when John and Mary get the forwarded email in their inboxes, the "To: " field should show that it was sent to "jack@agency.org" and "webmasters@company.com"

So my question is, how can I get PHP's mail function to actually send an email to ONLY "john@company.com" and "mary@company.com" but NOT to "jack@agency.org", while still showing "jack@agency.org" in the "To: " field in the email that John and Mary get?

Is there some sort of header I can set that will show the address in the "To: " field but not actually send it to that address?

EDIT: existing code would be something like this:

```
$to = "To: jack@agency.org, webmasters@company.org";
$from = "From: bob@customer.ca";
$new_headers = $to."\r\n".$from."\r\n"."Bcc: john@company.org, mary@company.org"."\r\n";

mail("","Subject Here","message here", $new_headers);
```

This works and forwards it to John and Mary appropriately, but "jack@agency.org" will receive two copies of the email (one from the original sender and one from the forwarded copy).

Comment: Dear Jordan, which nice, fresh and hopefully awesome code do you have so far? Otherwise it's kind of poking in the dark...

Comment: @Jan added some code I've been working with

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to **not** send a message to someone listed as a recipient, unless you're using something like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html).

However you should be able to do something like alter the `/etc/mail/address.resolve` file, or if that doesn't work or is non-existent, another option could be to alter the actual `/etc/hosts` file so that it thinks `example.org` points to the same IP address as `localhost`:

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 localhost example.org
```

Comment: How would I do this if I wanted to actually send it to "name1@example.com", and have "name2@example.com" show up in the "To: " field without actually receiving it? If I edit the resolve file to link that domain with the wrong address, then even the person who SHOULD receive it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Instead of using PHP's `mail()` function, I used the `exec()` function to call `sendmail` from the command line. With sendmail, you can specify different to: and envelope-to: headers. So the code would look something like this:

```
$message = "To: jack@agency.org, webmasters@company.com\r\nFrom: bob@customer.ca\r\nSubject: subject line\r\n\r\n message content here";

exec("/usr/bin/sendmail john@company.com mary@company.com <<< ".escapeshellarg($message));
```

Then it actually only gets delivered to "john@company.com" and "mary@company.com", but to them it looks like it was sent to "jack@agency.org" and "webmasters@company.com".